# Pulse+ Pulse- with stepper motors

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I want to send Step/Direction signals from Trinamic Steprocker to a stepper driver (Chinese and unfortunately with no data sheet).

The problem is that this driver requires 4 signals (Pulse+ Pulse- Direction+ Direction-) while the Trinamic Steprocker driver can just send Direction and Steps (Just two signals).

Has anyone an idea about how to interface these two drivers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It may just be the anode and cathode polarity indicators for an optically isolated drive signals.  Here is an example product with similar terminology from Rhinomc RMCS-225X:

http://www.active-robots.com/dc-servo-motor-10rpm-uart-12c-ppm-drive

[image: rhinomc]

If you open the datasheet you will see the internal diodes. They leave all of them independently floating in order to allow the user to drive them as needed. (Common anode, common cathode, differential).

Answer (score 0):

The presence of signals whose names differ only by "+" and "-" strongly suggests that differential signalling is being used — perhaps something like RS-422.

There is no real way to verify this without opening up the unit and trying to identify the chip(s) that these signals drive.

If it turns out that this is the case, you'll need a TTL-to-RS422 driver chip, which is readily available.